# Added coolant repair to my car

Tags: coolant, repair

I added coolant repair to my car. how long do i have to wait to add coolant into the tank? I’ve waited 20 mins after i poured the coolant repair in and the engine has cooled.

Answer (score 2):

Read and follow the instructions on the product label for best results.

Beyond that, not much else can be said based on what little information you have provided.